# Dreamweaver doesn't load cache buster css

Tags: html, caching, dreamweaver

I've added the cache buster trick to my CSS stylesheet ?ver=v1.0 however when I locally load the website via dreamweaver it doesn't apply the styles. It works fine when uploaded to a server, but offline i just see a white page with text and no styles applied.

I've messed about with using PHP for example  but it still doesnt load. It will only work if the page is loaded by

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css">`
```

and with no version number.

The code i've tried is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css<?php echo '?ver=1'; ?>">
```

Is there anyway to get this app to load the stylesheet local using the test.css?ver=1 or is just a case of adding the version manually each time I upload.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I have had this issue before. I never found a solution though. The trouble is, Dreamweaver isn't a server, it doesn't know how to interpret php and therefore I believe that it is just ignoring the whole css link altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow up the only workaround I found was to use jquery to append the ?ver=1 after the stylesheet was loaded, by adding the id='test'. Hopefully someone knows a prettier work around.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "#test" ).attr( "href", "css/test.css?ver.1" );
});
```